# Using findAll PagingAndSortingRepository with filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the need to use the PagingAndSortingRepository in order to obtain a list of element. I also need to filter this list with a RequestParam.

In the controller I have:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/listfilter", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<Element> getElements(
        @RequestParam("page") int page,
        @RequestParam("size") int size,
        @RequestParam("aaa") String filter) {

    Filter filter = new Filter();
    filter.setPageNum(page);
    filter.setPageSize(size);
    filter.setAaa(aaa);

    return controller.findElements(filter);
}
```

How can I pass the filtered list to the method

```
Page<Element> findElements(Pageable pageable) {...}
```

Thank you

Comment: Combine it with a `JpaSpecificationExecutor`... That allows you to define a `Specification` and combine it with paging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing 'aaa' is a string (username or smth), with Spring JPA in `PagingAndSortingRepository` you could do something like this:

`Page<Element> findAllByAaa(String aaaValue, Pageable pageable)`;

Url might look like: `/elements/aaa?page=pageNr&size=nrOfElemOnPage`

It will iterate on your table, select the elements where `aaa = aaaValue`, put them into Pageable

In my opinion this is a better and cleaner aproach.

Comment: Yes, in fact I'm going in this direction, but I'm not so keen on Pageable class: how it can fix the page number and the page size that I receive from the request? 

Thank you

Comment: You can use method(@PathVariable("aaa")String aaa, @RequestParam(value = "size")String size, @RequestParam(value = "page")String page)

Comment: superb.  Thank you.