# Springboot JPA Pageable not working for page number greater then 0

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to get the Results Paginated, The below code works fine if the request is made with page parameter set to 0 but it doesn't work for page>0 like page=1 or page=2 or page=3 etc.

Here is my RequestMapping

```
MyResponse getSample(@ModelAttribute MyRequest MyRequest) {
        Pageable pageRequest =  new PageRequest(MyRequest.page, MyRequest.size)
        MyModule.findSamples(MyRequest, pageRequest)
    }



class MyRequest {

    MyQueryType queryType


    String searchTerm


    @Min(value = 0L, message = 'Offset must be greater than or equal to 0')
    int offset = 0

    @Min(value = 0L, message = 'Offset must be greater than or equal to 0')
    int page = 0

    @Min(value = 1L, message = 'Limit must be greater than or equal to 1')
    int limit = 100

    @Min(value = 1L, message = 'Limit must be greater than or equal to 1')
    int size = 5
}


MyModule:Code inside my Module



MyResponse findSamples(MyRequest MyRequest, Pageable pageRequest) {
            log.info("Page Information Set "+pageRequest.pageNumber+pageRequest.pageSize)
            Page<SamplesPO> pages = null
            pages = MyRepository.findAllById(MyRequest.Id, pageRequest)
            }
```

Repository Code:

```
public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Sample, Long> {

        @Query('''
        select e.Samples
        from ParentSampleTable e
        where e.Id = :Id
    ''')
    Page<Sample> findAllById(@Param('Id') String Id, Pageable pageRequest)
}
```

Comment: This is SPring Data JPA API (!= JPA API). Pageable/Repository is nothing to do with JPA API. Tags fixed

Answer (score 2):

Read PageRequest java docs before Using below code. PageRequest 
 request works on page number(starts from index 0 to 1,2,3 and so 
 on)    and the size( limit you want)

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "mfgDate");

Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize, sort);

 @Repository
 public interface BikeRepository extends MongoRepository<Bike, String> {
        Page<Bike> findByCompanyId(String companyId, Pageable pageable);
    }
```

Comment: In Spring Boot 2.7.x (not sure about lower versions), the constructor PageRequest(int, int, Sort) is not visible and you have to use `Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, sort);` instead

Answer (score 0):

You could try extracting the `id` with `@PathParam`

Method `getSample` annotated with `@GetMapping` with params `(@PathParam("id") String id, Pageable pageable)` and it could return `sampleRepository.findAllById(id, pageable)`

Url might look like: `/samples/id?page=pageNr&size=nrOfElemOnPage`

Your repository should return 
`Page<Sample> findAllById(String id, Pageable pageable)`

Also please consider refactoring(indention) the code before posting it to stackoverflow

Also this might be a duplicate: [Using findAll PagingAndSortingRepository with filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677581/using-findall-pagingandsortingrepository-with-filter/41678205#41678205)

Comment: I was able to resolve  the issue by writing my own PageRequest class that implemented Pageable Interface. First I have SearchRequest class in place of PathParam id, second I do not get page in the URL. I get offset and limit in the SearchRequest. And most important of all the @query was returning the Child records from Parent table so I had to rewrite the Query to return Child records from Child table by creating a Join to the Parent table.