# PagingAndSortingRepository filter by field on URL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

may I ask if it is possible to filter Spring Boot entities by fields on URL? For example, I have a class called Employee with fields first name and last name. And I would like to filter by last name. I first tried something like: localhost:8080/api/employees?lastName=aaa but result is all entries in database.

Then I followed accepted answer in this post: [Using findAll PagingAndSortingRepository with filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677581/using-findall-pagingandsortingrepository-with-filter) but it is not working either.

Here is my code:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long> {

Page<Employee> findAllByLastName(String lastName, Pageable pageable);
```

}

but this request only gives bad result:

```
localhost:8080/api/employees/lastName&page=0&size=2
```

result

```
{
"cause": {
    "cause": null,
    "message": "For input string: \"lastName&page=0&size=2\""
},
"message": "Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'lastName&page=0&size=2'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"lastName&page=0&size=2\""
```

}

Comment: You can create flexible searches with zero code as outlined in the answer referenced above. The 2 answers below require query methods (and possibly controller endpoints) to be added for every combination of search parameters which is obviously not optimal. If you are using Spring Data Rest extension (which you probably are but have not tagged then much the same but obviously without the MVC endpoints).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code snippets.

```
@GetMapping("/api/search")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> serachUsers(@RequestParam("lastName") String lastName, Pageable pageable) {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findByLastNameContaining(lastName, pageable);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(users);
}
```

Create Reposity with

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findByLastNameContaining(String lastName, Pageable pageable);
}
```

then try with below curl

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/api/search?lastName=test&page=0&size=2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom search functions in Spring Data JPA REST endup under `search/`. Try the below

```
localhost:8080/api/employees/search/findAllByLastName?lastName=Sadakath&page=0&size=2
```